# how to change permissions of a drive that's read-only on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix, ubuntu-20.04

On the same hard disk I have a drive that's read-only .
I tried to change the permissions manually from properties but it doesn't . I don't know what to do .
thanks in advance

Comment: Well, it's read-only. It means you can't change anything on it, but only read it. Make the disk not read-only.

Comment: And how could that be done  ?

Comment: We'd have to figure out why it's read-only in the first place. Please [edit] your post to include output of the `mount` command and tell us which drive it is.

Comment: Possible not enough permission on the mount file. See solution in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1207427/how-to-enable-full-permissions-on-internal-secondary-hdd